# Load variable in angularJS before before javascript html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, angular-template

I am trying to load a graph in `AmCharts`.

The problem is that the JavaScript script is loaded before I get the service return, it starts empty and I can not update the variable.

Any idea how to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {{json}} );
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an Angular wrapped version of AmCharts that supports async data/promises. [Here's an example](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular)

Comment: What do you mean before the service return ?

Comment: The html is loaded (javascript script) and then the variable json receives a json with the graphic to display. Basically I do not have the graph ready on loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can [boostrap your angular application using javascript](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

basically you remove your ng-app attribute and run this:

```
angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: I can not remove the ng-app because there are other features that use it.

Comment: @TiagoJavaman you can try to add the attribute in javascript `$('#item').attr('ng-app', 'app');` maybe that will work.

Comment: What would be #item ? 
Do you have an example?

Comment: @TiagoJavaman id of the element that should have the ng-app `<div id="item" ng-app="app">` -> `<div id="item"></div>`, you can use other css selector like `$('div:eq(0)').attr('ng-app', 'app');` for first div.